# Update Webpack without ejecting Create-React-App

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, create-react-app

Currently using react-scripts: 5.0.1

I need to update Webpack to at least 5.76.0 but I don't want to eject Create-React-App.

What are my options?

Answer (score 0):

React-Scripts will likely release an update soon to upgrade webpack.

In the mean time you can add this to your package.json to force the update.

```
  "resolutions": {
    "webpack": "5.76.0"
  }
```

Comment: I'm using npm and I don't want to migrate to yarn. Will override achieve the same thing? `{"overrides": {"webpack": "5.76.0"}}`